# Accessing current case as a variable

Tags: c#

I am using switch..case to display different things on my page depending on the product id:

```
            switch (productID)
            {
                case 1:
                    string theSQL = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = " + theCurrentCase + "ORDER BY id DESC";
                    DataTable theDT = dbConnectionAndQuery.dbResults(theSQL, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mainConn"].ConnectionString);
                    break;
            }
```

Is there any way to accessing the case value (i.e. 1 in the example above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`productID` would match `1` if that block of code was to be executed so you know already know what the case value is (it would be `productID`).

On a side note, don't concatenate your SQL statement like that as it leaves you vulnerable to SQL injections. Use [Parameters](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) instead. In this case it would have to match `1` to execute but other cases may not be safe (e.g. possibly in your `default` case if you have one). It's good practice to use `Parameters` when creating SQL queries.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. This is just for a local site, so I am not using parameters just out of laziness. But thanks for the concern anyway.

Comment: You can also add a evaluated column with a known name to represent the case that applied.             "SELECT *, 1 as theSelectedCase FROM products WHERE id = " + theCurrentCase + "ORDER BY id DESC";

Answer (score 7):

Of course, use `productID` :)

`filler`

`filler`

Comment: Mind drew a blank. Oh so simple! Thanks for the response!

Comment: If the `switch` section in question has only *one* `case` label (and no `default` label), like in the question, then you can use the same constant, here `1`. If the section has more than one `case` label and/or the `default` label, you can use the `switch` expression again, here `productID`, just like in this answer. However the expression will be evaluated again, of course, and if it is expensive to evaluate or if it may evaluate to a new value second time (like `switch (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek) { ... }`), it would be good to introduce a local variable just before the `switch` statement.